# How far can a wolf drag a 175 lb human on tundra?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, encumbrance

One of my players is arguing that a wolf cannot drag a 175 lb human including gear more than 5 ft when on tundra.

How far can they drag them?

Comment: I'm guessing this human is dead or unable/unwilling to resist being dragged, is this correct?

Answer (score 15):

### 50 ft. per movement action, or 25ft. if the terrain is difficult.

A normal [wolf](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/wolf.htm) is a quadruped medium creature with a strength score of 13.

As per the [carrying capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/carryingCapacity.htm) rules, this means that it can drag up to **1,125 lb.** under normal conditions.

Further, according to the Frostburn p.27 handbook, tundra terrain can be difficult terrain (depending on the characteristics of the zone), but it doesn't mention carrying capacity. However, the carrying capacity rules about dragging do mention bad circumstances can reduce carrying capacity to one-half or less, without giving any more indications. The weight limit under such circumstances would be up to the DM.

Dragging something doesn't seem to incur any special penalty, there's just a limit to how much weight you can drag. Therefore, the wolf wouldn't have any penalty because of dragging this body.

Comment: Also, read this question for a different interpretation: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28030/penalties-for-pushing-dragging, I had always assumed dragging something had the same penalties as being encumbered, but it's seems it isn't as clear cut.

Comment: That's the weight of a small car. I'm not saying it's not RAW, but no wolf can drag a half ton of weight along at that speed.

Comment: @DJClayworth the numbers for a wolf also indicate it can potentially slay commoners in a single bite, and its fur is roughly as durable as chainmail. The world of 3.5e is apparently quite a scary place.